# I can't use dio_extension php

Tags: php

I've downloaded dio extension->php_dio.dll (version 5.2.6.6) and put it in extension dir php then put extension=php_dio.dll in php.ini then restart the apache.

in phpinfo() shows: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZZk7.png)

I read in some forum that it's old version of dio extension.

I've tried to run [this script](http://www.cyberspice.org.uk/blog/2010/02/02/php-dio-extension-looking-for-beta-testers/):

```
<?php 
    // Create a stream context that configures the serial port
    // And enables canonical input.
    $c = stream_context_create(array('dio' => 
        array('data_rate' => 115200, 
              'data_bits' => 8, 
              'stop_bits' => 1, 
              'parity' => 0, 
              'is_canonical' => 1)));

    // Are we POSIX or Windows?  POSIX platforms do not have a
    // Standard port naming scheme so it could be /dev/ttyUSB0
    // or some long /dev/tty.serial_port_name_thingy on OSX.
    if (PATH_SEPARATOR != ";") {
        $filename = "dio.serial:///dev/ttyS0";
    } else {
        $filename = "dio.serial://COM5";
    }

    // Open the stream for read only and use it.
    $f = fopen($filename, "r+", false, $c);
    if ($f) {
        echo "Writing to port...\n";
        fprintf($f,"Hello world\n");
        echo "Reading from port...\n";
        $data = fgets($f);
        if ($data) {
            echo $data;
        }
        fclose($f);
    }
?>
```

but I always get **Warning: fopen(dio.serial://COM5) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in**

dio extension does not work in windows? or i'm using a old version?

if i'm using a old version, where can i find the newer version of dio extension.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`dio_open()`](http://php.net/dio_open). And the latest release on the PECL servers is [`0.0.4RC4`](http://pecl.php.net/package/dio). What you have there is a mislabeled pre-release of [`0.0.2`](http://www.powerplacedr.com/temp/download/dio-0.0.2/) instead.

If you want to [pander](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.windows.php) further options (rather than checking the permission thingy mentioned last time), then [`socat`](http://www.rfc1149.net/blog/2011/12/01/accessing-serial-ports-the-easy-way/) might be. It maps devices onto sockets. A Windows (Cygwin) binary of that exists.

Also, while I don't want to berate anyone for personal preferences. You wouldn't have those problems if you didn't insist on using Windows.

> Comments will not be answered.